# mailx works, but mutt has stopped working

Tags: mutt, smtp, mailx

RHEL 8.4

I've got a script (run via cron, if it makes a difference, though the same problems occur interactively) which sends an email (through a corporate smtp server) based on several conditions.

If there are no attachments to send, then a simple text-only email is sent via `mailx`:

```
echo "blarge" | mailx -s "Mumble" $ADDR
```

If a CSV file needs to be sent, this command is executed:

```
echo $CSVDATA | mutt -e 'set content_type=text/html' -s "Blarge" $ADDR
```

The contents of `~/.muttrc` is just:

```
set smtp_url="smtp://ourcorporatesmptservername"
```

This has been working perfectly for years, but emails sent from mutt stopped arriving Monday.

Now, not even `echo "blarge" | mutt -s "Mumble" $ADDR` works.

I suspect a configuration change on the local system, but don't know where to look to see if mailx emails are being sent to a new smtp server.  (Nothing listens on port 25 on the local system.)